# Rollback Inserts/Updates/Deletes in linq pad?

Tags: linq, rollback, linqpad

I found [this article](http://www.squaredroot.com/2007/12/05/addupdatedelete-with-linqpad/) about how to insert, update and delete using linq pad but it mentions nothing about rolling back anything.

Is it possible to rollback in linqpad?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You can do:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
  // Put the operations that you want to protect in a transaction here.

  if (you_want_to_commit) {
    scope.Complete();
  }
  // Otherwise, it'll roll back when you exit the using block.
}
```

Comment: How I understand Complete is if nothing crashes then no rollback is done. I want to do a commit but then a rollback right away even if everything went fine. So It would be basically like Begin Tran.... RollBack Tran in a sql query.

Comment: If you want to actually send to the server (even if you roll back later), you do a SubmitChanges()